# Difference between istream::read and istream::operator>>

Tags: c++

Here are two snippets of code which I at first thought should be equivalent:

```
{
    std::ifstream stream("test.bin", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
    unsigned char count = 128;
    unsigned char read = 0;
    unsigned char scanline[128];
    long long start = stream.tellg();
    while (count--) {
        stream >> scanline[read++]; // <---- This is the only line which differs
    }
    long long end = stream.tellg();
    std::cout << end - start << "\n";
}

{
    std::ifstream stream("test.bin", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
    unsigned char count = 128;
    unsigned char read = 0;
    unsigned char scanline[128];
    long long start = stream.tellg();
    while (count--) {
        stream.read((char*)&scanline[read++], 1); // <---- This is the only line which differs
    }
    long long end = stream.tellg();
    std::cout << end - start << "\n";
}
```

My problem is that the first version outputs 153 (probably dependent on input data) and the second one outputs 128 (which is what I expected). This must have something to do with how data is extracted in the first version but I fail to understand why it doesn't work. Shouldn't it just call:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& is, unsigned char& ch);
```

and move the filepos one byte each time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you read the description for `operator>>` (e.g. [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)), then you will see that it skips whitespace before reading, until it hits whitespace again. Whitespace is not only space (`0x20`) but also things like tab (`0x09`)  and newline (`0x0a`).

So if your binary data contains bytes that are considered whitespace for a text file, then `operator>>` will read but not store them, which will skew the numbers reported by `tellg`.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a good Idea to use the `operator>>` when you open a stream in binary.
I assume that in your case there is some sort of white space character(e.g 0x20) in your stream.
You could use the `skipws` modifier that those are also read.

Comment: It's not a question of whether you open the stream in binary or not; it's whether the stream contains binary data.  (It's common to open text streams in binary, and handle the line ending conventions in your code.)